# Does reject_if act on the parent model, or the child, when a symbol is used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, model-associations

The documentation for ActiveRecord nested attributes mentions being able to use a symbol for `:reject_if`:

> Alternatively, :reject_if also accepts a symbol for using methods:
>
> ```
> class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :posts
>   accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, reject_if: :new_record?
> end
>
> class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
>   has_many :posts
>   accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, reject_if: :reject_posts
>
>   def reject_posts(attributes)
>     attributes['title'].blank?
>   end
> end
> ```

I assume that `new_record?` is a method that'd be called on a model of class `Post` (the child object), but `reject_posts` is a method called on a model of class `Member` (the parent object).

What's going on here? Does it try calling the method on both the parent and the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called on the parent. What `reject_if` does is reject the hash of attributes if the predicate fails. This occurs before the hash is used to initialize a new record so calling it on the child is not applicable/possible.

Comment: And `new_record?` is being called on the parent as well?

Comment: Yes it is. Both the accept and reject options work on the parent since there is no instance of the nested model to call on - just a hash of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get to the parent instance, use Symbol like:

```
... reject_if: :call_a_parent_instance_method

def call_a_parent_instance_method(attrs)
  # here self is a parent instance and I have access to child attributes :)
end
```

The inline proc symbol like

```
... reject_if: proc {|attrs| this_instance_method_call_will_raise_exception }
```

will not give you access to the parent's instance.

From any of scenarios you cannot access child instance.

Comment: It is called on parents by default isn't it??  Why do you have to talk about parent instance again??